# Arduino Nano Timers

Tags: timer, arduino, avr, atmel, atmega

I want to know more about [Arduino Nano](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-nano) timers.

1. What timers are there?
2. Do they produce interrupts?
3. What code would attach an interrupt handler to them?
4. How is `delay()` and `delayMicroseconds()` implemented...

   - Do they use timer interrupts? (If so, how can I have other code execute during this?)
   - Or do they repeatedly poll until a timer reaches a certain value?
   - Or do they increment a value X number of times?
   - Or do they do it another way?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The best way to think about the Arduino Nano timers is to think about the timers in the underlying chip: the [ATmega328](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet.pdf). It has three timers:

- Timer 0: 8-bit, PWM on chip pins 11 and 12
- Timer 1: 16-bit, PWM on chip pins 15 and 16
- Timer 2: 8-bit, PWM on chip pins 17 and 5

All of these timers can produce two kinds of interrupts:

- The "value matched" interrupt occurs when the timer value, which is added to every tick of the timer reaches a comparison value in the timer register.
- The timer overflow interrupt occurs when the timer value reaches its maximum value

Unfortunately, there is no Arduino function to attach interrupts to timers. To use timer interrupts you will need to write slightly more low-level code. Basically, you will need to declare an [interrupt routine](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html) something like this:

```
ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect) {
   ...
}
```

This will declare a function to service timer1 overflow interrupt. Then you will need to *enable* the timer overflow interrupt using the `TIMSK1` register. In the above example case this might look like this:

```
TIMSK1 |= (1<<TOIE1);
```

or

```
TIMSK1 |= BV(TOIE1);
```

This sets the `TOIE1` (generate timer1 overflow interrupt, please) flag in the TIMSK1 register. Assuming that your interrupts are enabled, your `ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect)` will get called every time timer1 overflows.

---

The Arduino `delay()` function looks as follows in the source code (`wiring.c`):

```
void delay(unsigned long ms)
{
    uint16_t start = (uint16_t)micros();

    while (ms > 0) {
        if (((uint16_t)micros() - start) >= 1000) {
            ms--;
            start += 1000;
        }
    }
}
```

So internally it uses the `micros()` function, which indeed relies on the timer0 count. The Arduino framework uses timer0 to count milliseconds, indeed, timer0 count is is where `millis()` function gets its value.

The `delayMicroseconds()` function, on the other hand, uses certain well-timed microprocessor operations to create the delay; which function is used depends on the processor and the clock speed; the most common being `nop()` (no operation) which takes exactly one clock cycle. Arduino Nano uses a 16 MHz clock, and here's what the source code looks like for that:

```
// For a one-microsecond delay, simply return. The overhead
// of the function call yields a delay of approximately 1 1/8 µs.
if (--us == 0)
    return;

// The following loop takes a quarter of a microsecond (4 cycles)
// per iteration, so execute it four times for each microsecond of
// delay requested.
us <<= 2;

// Account for the time taken in the proceeding commands.
us -= 2;
```

What we learn from this:

- 1 µs delay does nothing (the function call is the delay)
- Longer delays use the left shift operation to time the delay.

Comment: Thanks! Glad you found it to be useful.